# PHP 5.4 Built-in web server on home network

Tags: php, php-5.4

I'm running the PHP 5.4 built-in web server on my desktop PC. I can access my webpage on that same PC, but I was hoping I could access the page on my tablet as well.

Is there any way I can open it up so I can access my page anywhere on my home network?

Comment: you can port forward and use your external IP address, although this seems a little extreme for a home network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8377378/2629998) you should be able to make PHP listen on all interfaces using a command-line parameter :

For Windows :

```
C:/php/php.exe -S 0.0.0.0:80
```

or, for GNU/Linux :

```
/usr/bin/php -S 0.0.0.0:80
```

Comment: A note for other idiots like me: you have to use the IP of the machine running the server from your other devices; "localhost" won't work. (I had a brain fart)

Comment: Yes Andre... I couldn't accept your answer at the time. Had to wait another 9 minutes. You may have the checkmark.