# PHP built-in webserver serves different webpages depending on access address?

Tags: php, webserver, command-line-interface

I've been using the 5.4+ built-in webserver in PHP cli, invoked via:

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

... and all looks fine on the local PC when accessing `http://localhost:8080`. So I wanted to test from another device on the local network, but the `localhost` invocation does not make the server available on the local network. So, I've found that `0.0.0.0` can be used to listen on all interfaces ([Running PHP 5.4 built-in web server outside localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377178/running-php-5-4-built-in-web-server-outside-localhost)), and I tried that invocation:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Now, I try to access this from the device, and I notice some links cannot be clicked. I try to investigate back on the local PC which hosts the PHP server; and there, when I issue:

```
http://localhost:8080/dir/
```

... the server logs it as (there is `index.php` in `/dir/`):

```
[Thu Oct 22 22:56:02 2015] 127.0.0.1:59752 [200]: /dir/
```

... and this one works fine, no problem.

But when I call the local IP of the computer, for instance:

```
http://192.168.0.150:8080/dir/
```

... PHP logs it as:

```
[Thu Oct 22 22:56:14 2015] 192.168.0.150:57847 [200]: /dir/
```

... and this page I cannot click ???!!!!???!

So, I saved the server HTML in both cases, ran a diff, and turns out there are differences like:

```
...
 <!-- </div> -->
-<div style="width: 612px;" class="testB my_class" id="testB">
+<div class="testB" id="testB">
 <div class="test" id="test">
...
```

So, basically, the very same instance of the PHP cli server, serves two different pages, based on the address it was called by????!!!

Anyone have any idea why? Version:

```
$ php --version
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13 (cli) (built: Sep 29 2015 15:16:25)
```

Comment: "Warning
This web server was designed to aid application development. It may also be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations that are run in controlled environments. It is not intended to be a full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network." - http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: Thanks @symcbean - but as I noted, here both the browser and the php server run on the very same computer; that's hardly a public network.