# URL of localhost not working

Tags: php, localhost

I launched a webpage(only one file *index.php*) on localhost port 8000 with the command

```
    php -S localhost:8000
```

My private IP address is **192.168.1.109** and I try accessing the webpage from a mobile phone on the same network, with the link

```
    http://192.168.1.109:8000/index.php
```

But I'm unable to access it. Any suggestions?

Comment: firewall on your pc?

Comment: Is the phone on the same network as the computer?

Comment: Here you will get about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377178/running-php-5-4-built-in-web-server-outside-localhost

Comment: I'm using linux, does it have firewall issues? And yes the phone is on the same network.

Comment: you need to do a lot more if you want your to access your webpage using your IP address.

Comment: @VenkatLokeswar thanks, that works. Does that mean I shouldn't ever use localhost? I mean what's the use of localhost then?

Comment: localhost=> 127.0.0.1  that means you are accessing self. It only works in your system. So the server runs for you system only,

Answer (score 0):

You told the server to listen on `localhost`, so that is what it is doing. It is listening on `127.0.0.1` (or possibly `::1` if you're defaulting to IPv6).

If you want it to listen on `192.168.1.109` then you have to tell it to do that:

```
php -S 192.168.1.109:8000
```

Or tell it to listen on all network interfaces:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000
```